# Центрировать по вертикали изображение в :before

Tags: html, css

Сразу хочу отметить, что я гуглил, но, по какой-то причине, способы, предлагаемые на русском и английском StackOverflow/Exchange) не работают в моем случае.

```html
<div class="about">
  <div class="name">Джон Доу</div>
  <div class="profile">Профиль</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
.about {
  width: 100%;
  height: 24px;
  line-height: 24px;
}
.name {
  float: left;
}
.profile {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 40px;
}
.profile:before {
  content: url("images/profile.png");
}
```

Нужно как-то оцентрировать по-вертикали картинку, добавляемую через `:before`.

[image].

Как видно на картинке, способ, предложенный `Deonis` сдвигает картинку немного вниз, но она все-еще не оцентрирована по-вертикали.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если именно изображение добавляемое с помощью псевдокласса и относительно контента в его родительском элементе, то можно так:

```
.profile:before {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 1;
    content: url("images/profile.png");
}
```

Дополнение к комментарию. Ощутите разницу: в первом варианте, как есть у вас и во втором варианте, где использован предложенный мной выше способ.

```css
.about {
  width: 100%;
  height: 24px;
  line-height: 24px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.name {
  float: left;
}
.profile {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 40px;
  outline: 1px solid #999;
}
.profile:before {
  content: url("http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/paomedia/small-n-flat/16/profile-icon.png");
}
.variant2:before {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="about">
  <div class="name">Джон Доу</div>
  <div class="profile">Профиль</div>
</div>
<div class="about">
  <div class="name">Джон Доу</div>
  <div class="profile variant2">Профиль</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Нужно относительно контента в элементе с классом profile. Ваш текущий ответ, к сожалению, не решает проблему. Иконка как висела вверху, так и висит.

Comment: @user64675, дополнил в ответе

Comment: Ошибся, действительно есть результат, но как видно при выполнении вашего кода, это все-равно не центрирование строго по середине по-вертикали, это небольшой отступ :/

Comment: @user64675, линейкой я не замерял, однако знаю, что человеческий глаз уж точно не пригоден для точных измерений. Возьмём [пример покрупнее](https://jsfiddle.net/7jyfush3/).

Comment: Ок, уточню, картинка меньше по высоте, чем 24px. И вот там, как раз, и есть та проблема с тем, что выравнивание не полное.

Comment: @user64675, сложно делать какие-то предположения, т.к. я не вижу всей картины в целом, не вижу изображения, которое вы используете, не знаю о других стилях, которые могут влиять на поведение рассматриваемых элементов. Единственное, что могу еще посоветовать - это попробовать обернуть текст "Профиль" в `<span>`, которому так же установить свойства `display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;`

Comment: Секунду, я приложу в вопрос картинку, где поясняю.
Из других стилей только CSS Reset

Comment: Готово, прошу посмотреть.

Comment: @user64675, попробуйте для псевдокласса добавить `line-height: 1;`

Comment: Теперь идеально :) Измените ответ, пожалуйста?

Answer (score 0):

.profile - флотнут, поэтому vertical-align: middle работать не будет.
Варианты: 
1. Увеличить левый отступ и повесить картинку на абсолют:

```css
.profile {
   float: left;
   margin-left: 60px;
   position: relative;
}
.profile:before {
   content: "";
   display: block;
   width: 20px;
   height: 20px;
   background-image: url("images/profile.png");
   background-size: cover;
   position:absolute;
   right: 100%;
   top: 50%;
  transform: translatey(-50%);
}
```

2. Добавить дочерний элемент:

```css
.about {
  width: 100%;
  height: 24px;
  line-height: 24px;
}
.name {
  float: left;
}
.profile {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 40px;
}
.child {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.child:before {
  content: url("images/profile.png");
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="about">
  <div class="name">Джон Доу</div>
  <div class="profile">
    <div class="child">Профиль</div>
  </div>
</div>
```